# collection of independent events

Tags: probability-theory

I'm studying the book Probabilities: theory and examples, of Durrett.
On page 26 of third edition there is a corollary:

Corollary: Suppose $\mathcal{F}_{i,j}$, $1\leq i\leq n$, $1\leq j\leq m(i)$ are independent and let $\mathcal{G}_i=\sigma(\cup_j\mathcal{F}_{i,j})$. Then $\mathcal{G}_1,...,\mathcal{G}_n$ are independent.

Proof: Let $\mathcal{A}_i$ be the collection of sets of the form $\cap_jA_{i,j}$, where $A_{i,j}\in\mathcal{F}_{i,j}$. Then $\mathcal{A}_i$ is closed under intersection that contains $\Omega$ and contains $\cup_j\mathcal{F}_{i,j}$ (this last statement isn't clear for me, why $\mathcal{A}_i$ contains $\cup_j\mathcal{F}_{i,j}$?). Then we have $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_i)=\mathcal{G}_i$ are independent, by $\pi-\lambda$-theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B\in \cup_j\mathcal{F}_{i,j}$ implies $B\in \mathcal{F}_{i,j_0}$ for some $1\le j_0\le m(i)$, therefore $B$ is of the form $\cap_jA_{i,j}$ with $A_{i,j}=\Omega\in\mathcal{F}_{i,j}$ for $j\neq j_0$ and $A_{i,j_0}=B\in\mathcal{F}_{i,j_0}$.